# Multiplication with decimal results in incorrect value in SQL Server 2016

Tags: sql, sql-server

When I run the query:

```
(SELECT (CONVERT(DECIMAL, COUNT(SequenceId)) * 0.6)  FROM dbo.usvSequenceToSequence_WithSequenceId)
```

I get the result:
17550.0

However, when I run the query:

```
DECLARE @percentageOfSliceAsDecimal DECIMAL
    SET @percentageOfSliceAsDecimal = 0.6
(SELECT (CONVERT(DECIMAL, COUNT(SequenceId)) * @percentageOfSliceAsDecimal)  FROM dbo.usvSequenceToSequence_WithSequenceId)
```

I get the result:
29250

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to declare with appropriate precision:

```
declare @d decimal(10,2) = 0.6
select(convert(decimal,1982)*@d)
```

It returns 1189.20

Whereas if we have only decimal

```
declare @d decimal = 0.6
select(convert(decimal,1982)*@d)
```

It returns 1982 as it rounds to 1

Answer (score 2):

Decimal is not a "Floating" point number.  It is a fixed "non-Floating" number with a defined number of decimal digits on each side of the decimal point. The default is 18 digits to the left and zero (0), or no digits to the right.

SO, whatever you define it as controls what is stored. If you try and store more digits than are defined, the extra digits are rounded (if to the right), or ignored.

If you need accuracy to whatever decimal precision is entered, use a "float", or a "real".

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because the variable declared as DECIMAL doesn't have any values specified to the right of the decimal point (as per the definition here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/decimal-and-numeric-transact-sql), which is resulting in a rounding-up. This can be observed as follows:

```
DECLARE @percentageOfSliceAsDecimal DECIMAL
    SET @percentageOfSliceAsDecimal = 0.6
    SELECT @percentageOfSliceAsDecimal
```

result is 1

The solution is to do something like this instead:

```
DECLARE @percentageOfSliceAsDecimal DECIMAL(18,1)
    SET @percentageOfSliceAsDecimal = 0.6
    SELECT @percentageOfSliceAsDecimal
```

Comment: answer uses the word "Floating" values, which, although the educated might understand what is meant, would be confusing to a novice, as the entire issue here is that the op is using decimal data type, which is NOT a float. If he used a float, or a real, he would not have this issue